# UnityContainer.RegisterType does not get used when put in a Static Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

This is an example console application (it will run fine after adding the Unity NugGet package) that **seems to show a bug in Unity**:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

class GC { public static UnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GC.Container.RegisterType<MyView>();
        var myView = GC.Container.Resolve<MyView>();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyClassDesign: MyClass{}
public class MyClass: VMBase<MyClass, MyClassDesign>{}
public abstract class VMBase<TViewModel, TDesignVM> where TDesignVM:TViewModel
{
    static VMBase()
    {
        if (!GC.Container.IsRegistered(typeof(TViewModel)))
            GC.Container.RegisterType(typeof (TViewModel), typeof(TDesignVM));
    }
}

public class MyView
{
    public MyView(MyClass myClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bad: "+myClass.GetType().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Good: "+GC.Container.Resolve<MyClass>().GetType());
    }
}
```

The output is:

> Bad: MyClass
>   Good: MyClassDesign

The resolved type is `MyClass`.  But it should be `MyClassDesign`.  (The static constructor runs prior to MyClass being resolved in the `MyView` class.)

**How can I get Unity to allow me to setup my Mapping in the Static Constructor?**

Note: When I changed this setup the UnityContainer with a file (instead of in code) it all works fine.  But I would rather not be dependent on an external file for this.  (I am making a reusable template that I don't want to have too many dependencies in.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to put the registration logic inside your view model at all? This couples your application code to the container which is never a good idea. Have a look at the concept of [Composition roots](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx).

All setup code for the DI container should be placed there.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt really a bug with Unity. The issue is that the static ctor is not run until an instance is requested (at which point unity still does not know about `MyClassDesign`). Which means that Unity has already started creating an instance of `MyClass` to fulfill the request. Any subsequent calls to `GC.Container.Resolve<MyView>();` will result in the output you expect. As Sebastian Weber suggests, putting all your setup code in a completely seperate location (so your classes are not dependent on a specific DI container) is the best option.